# Symfony2: getting form validation error on repeated field

Tags: php, symfony

I set up a very basic form to register an user (username + password). I would like to get the validations errors in my controller.

I found two ways to do that:

```
// In my controller:
$user = new User();
$form = $this->createForm(new UserType, $user);

$request = $this->get('request');

if($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
     $form->bind($request);

     if($form->isValid()) {
         // save user in DB
     } else {
         // First way
         $errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($user);

         // OR
         $errors = $form->getErrors();
     }
 }
```

Both methods work if I enter an username too short in the form for example (there is a constraint MinLength on this field). But if I enter two different passwords, the form is invalid and there are no message errors in $form->getErrors() or $this->get('validator')->validate($user). How can I get this error message?

Here is how I build the form

```
$builder->add('username', 'text', array(
    'attr' => array(
       'placeholder' => 'Choose an username'
    ),
    'label' => 'Username *',
    'error_bubbling' => true,
));

$builder->add('password', 'repeated', array(
    'type' => 'password',
    'invalid_message' => 'The password fields must match.',
    'required' => true,
    'first_options'  => array(
        'label' => 'Password',
        'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Enter password')
    ),
    'second_options' => array(
        'label' => 'Repeat Password',
        'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Retype password')
    ),
    ));
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to get this message inside your controller?

Anyway, You've to call getErrors() for your `'password'` Field Type.
This should give you the `'The password fields must match.'` error.

```
$passwordErrors = $form->get('password')->getErrors();

foreach ($passwordErrors as $key => $error) {
      $message .= $error->getMessageTemplate(). '<br/>';
}
```

[`error_bubbling`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/repeated.html#error-bubbling) option is used to pass any errors of a given field to the parent field or form. In your example `error_bubbling` is set to true for the `username`, so you can get the username field validation error messages by calling getErrors() on the parent element ($form here). Which is not the case for the password repeated field unless you set `error_bubbling` option to true for this specific field too.

Comment: Thanks for your answser but it doesn't work. It returns an empty array. The reason I'd like to do that is because I try to validate this form trough ajax: I would like to return a response in JSON with a list of validation errors.

Comment: I just tested it using you own code and it works fine, I updated my answer. Set error_bublling for the password repeated field to true. You can then get the error using $form->getErrors().

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was the final solution, after a lot of attempts...

**FIRST:** Setting to false `error_bubbling` (or not set it, since false is the default value).

**SECOND:** Use the following code to get an `field` => `error_message` array.

```
    $errors = array();
    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        $fieldName = $child->getName();
        $fieldErrors = $form->get($child->getName())->getErrors(true);

        foreach ($fieldErrors as $fieldError){
            $errors[$fieldName] = $fieldError->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

This code should works on Symfony 3.4 / 4.1